# Based on my atypical (low) iPhone usage pattern, might the iPhone 13 Pro Max's larger battery last noticeably longer than the 13 Pro's?

Tags: iphone, battery, power

I've nursed my iPhone 6 through thick and thin and will now buy either iPhone 13 Pro or Pro/Max.

I am not a heavy phone user; for anything video or heavy browsing I prefer to pull out my laptop.

On a typical day I may browse Stack Exchange or news (static text, not video) or refer to maps or GPS for about 1 hour, and snap a dozen photos.

I almost always have a good cell phone signal where I live/work, and keep 4G data turned off except when using it.<sup>1</sup>

[This MacRumors link](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/09/24/iphone-13-battery-capacities-in-mah/) for example gives the battery sizes for iPhone 13 Pro and Pro/Max as 3,095 and 4,352 mAh. (couldn't find them [here](https://www.apple.com/iphone-13-pro/specs/))

**For me and my usage habits** which is different than that of some typical user profile, I am thinking that the Max's substantially larger battery will last longer between charges. It might not be a full 40% longer, but it might be noticeable.

**Question:** Based on my atypical (low) iPhone usage pattern, might the iPhone 13 Pro Max's larger battery last noticeably<sup>2</sup> longer than the 13 Pro's?

---

<sup>1</sup>"Why don't you keep your 4G on all the time?" Several non-negotiable reasons.

<sup>2</sup>"Define noticeably." If a number is required, then >20% longer. My thinking is that Pro Max users who are primarily watching video all day will be calculating and lighting 20% more pixels and screen than Pro users, so the larger battery size will be offset by the larger amount of power used, but for me who keeps the phone in my pocket 23 hours a day and avoids video, the larger batter should actually show up as a longer time between chargings.

Comment: 1) 4G uses less power than 3G, per byte. Not seeing how you're 'gaining battery' doing that, unless you are right on the very edge of 4G reception, in which case it will waste a lot of battery constantly swapping. 2) the Max series have a bigger battery, therefore longer life. This is part of Apple's marketing. The figures are easily available in many places.

Comment: BTW, if you're used to a 6, the Pro Max will feel like you're carrying a brick in your pocket. You'd also better like Face ID. I sent mine back within 24h & got an SE 2 instead. I charge it every two or three days, depending on [also low] usage.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've taken pains to explain why my usage pattern "is different than that of some typical user profile" and so the figure easily available in many places may not apply here. Ya I went to a store and got acclimated to the brickness, it's the price of doing business. but I didn't realize there was no thumbprint sensor. Yikes! It's the newest/latest three-eyed camera I'm primarily after, so I think the 13 Pro is the right one for me.

Comment: You're gonna love or hate the lack of a button. I loathed it. It's determined I will never have another reliant on the replacement swipe mechanism - designed for people with prehensile thumbs. I hated FaceID too, in this masked day & age, but it was the swipe that killed the deal. For me, it made almost all operations 2-handed. I did like the camera, but as I already have many thousands of pounds-worth of camera gear that will take ***far*** better photos, it wasn't a swayer. It was my favourite feature by far, though, a reasonably long lens on a phone has long been needed.

Comment: @Tetsujin oh geez now you have me thinking hard! [I miss my Pentax Spot-o-Matic but must choose a camera for amateur nature photography; get a new iPhone or an actual camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/121353/50110) I'd better revisit the showroom tomorrow; can you mention some specific photography thing that is particularly hard to do one-handed? Some killer test that will convince me to buy a real camera?

Comment: You need a long lens for wildlife. Even the relatively longer lens on the new phones only comes up at about 75mm, which is a good 'portrait' length for people shots, & nicely gets you out of that nasty hole phones have been in for so long - selfies, with 'big nose, little ears'… horrible.  But, I have a 300mm on my camera for wildlife & it's still not long enough sometimes, I need a 600mm ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin ya, my challenges are like dragonflies at 3 meters, birds at 10 meters, I guess I really do want a real camera. I will look at the SE, I didn't know it existed until you mentioned it, being dazzled by all the "latest and greatest" hype.

Comment: The SE is basically a 6S with a newer [iPhone 11] processor. Works for me. Has a button. Battery lasts for days with my usage. Didn't even have to buy a new case after my 6S, just cut a larger lens-hole for the newer, slightly larger lens [but the lens is still 20mm, big nose]. It does that fake bokeh thing like the bigger ones. It's OK, but real bokeh is better.

Comment: @Tetsujin got one! This is ***exactly*** what I wanted, whether I knew it or not :-) Now that I've saved about 200 [three dollar bills](https://guidetotaipei.com/article/new-taiwan-dollar-nt-twd-%E6%96%B0%E5%8F%B0%E5%B9%A3) I can go out and start looking for a nice camera :-)

Comment: @Tetsujin I've just asked [iPhone SE 2 changing between portrait and regular mode, what exactly is happening and how can I reduce my visual confusion/distraction?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/435370/143729)