# iPhone SE 2 changing between portrait and regular mode, what exactly is happening and how can I reduce my visual confusion/distraction?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I just upgraded from an iPhone 6 to an SE-2 and when I unlock my phone with the camera app running and bring it up to take a photo it usually switches between portrait and regular mode mid-swing.

I don't have any problems actually taking the photo, but that visual discontinuity as the image on the screen changes during the mode change still momentarily confuses/distracts me.<sup>1</sup>

Is there any way I can set the phone so that when I unlock it (with the camera app running) it comes up in regular mode and doesn't need to switch modes every time?

---

<sup>1</sup>It's great if it doesn't confuse/distract you, perhaps I'm your neurological inferior. But it does me so please no answers of the "What's wrong with you is..." variety, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings > Camera > Preserve Settings…

[image]

I t will let you switch off some of the 'return to default' settings & get whatever you last used.